# How to Create an Internal DSL in Scala?

Tags: scala, dns, dsl, specifications

I have been looking at a couple of books and resources on domain specific languages.
I think I want to build an internal DSL in Scala.

```
def instrument = new FXInstrument {

     provider = "EuroBase"
     instrumentOrders = List(
         new FXOrder {
             baseCcy = "GBP"
             termCcy = "EUR"
             legs = List( 
                 new FXLeg {
                    amountPrice = 100000.0
                    spotPrice = 1.56
                    requirements = List(
                        new FXRequirement {
                           baseCcy="GBP" termCcy="EUR" 
                           settlement="Banker Rain"
                        }
                    )
                 },
                 new FXLeg {
                    amountPrice = 200000.0
                    spotPrice = 1.50
                    requirements = List(
                        new FXRequirement {
                           baseCcy="GBP" termCcy="EUR" 
                           settlement="Banker Sunny"
                        }
                    )
                 }
             )

         }                  
}
```

Such that following asserts are valid:

```
 instrument.orders(0).baseCcy should equal ("GBP")
 instrument.orders(0).termCcy should equal ("EUR")
 instrument.orders(0).legs(0).amountPrice should equal 100000.0
 instrument.orders(0).legs(0).spotPrice should equal 1.56
 instrument.orders(0).legs(1).amountPrice should equal 200000.0
 instrument.orders(0).legs(1).spotPrice should equal 1.50
 instrument.orders(0).legs(0).requirements(0).settlement should equal "Banker Rain"
 instrument.orders(0).legs(1).requirements(0).settlement should equal "Banker Sunny"
```

I just do not know quite how to implement the domain specific language as an internal representation

1) new FXOrder() { /*closure*/ }

I like this syntax, is it good or should I prefer companion objects.
For instance I can quickly introduce other FX types easy.

2) I want to use "peers" such FXOrder is a scala.Proxy mixee, thus it uses the trait Proxy (mixin)

For example ``instrument.peer'' gives the internal peer Java Object of the third party proprietary API (a well known financial services trading system, can you guess?)

Ditto for

instrument.orders(0).peer
   instrument.orders(0).legs(0).peer
   instrument.orders(0).legs(0).requirements(0).peer

and so on.

I realise that domain specific language is not as simple as I thought, however some pointers on this above, would be really be useful. I would appreciate your responses. Ta!

*PP*

Comment: You can take a look at http://programming-scala.labs.oreilly.com/ch11.html#InternalDSLs

Answer (score 5):

Maybe, this can help you: [DSL in Scala](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/DomainSpecificLanguages.html)

Comment: This link has broken. :(

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Programming-Scala-Scalability-Functional-Objects/dp/0596155956%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAILSHYYTFIVPWUY6Q%26tag%3Dduckduckgo-d-20%26linkCode%3Dxm2%26camp%3D2025%26creative%3D165953%26creativeASIN%3D0596155956

Answer (score 5):

I haven't considered what you want yet, but I saw a problem:

> 1) new FXOrder() { /closure/ }

No, it doesn't work that way. When you follow an initialization (`new Something`) with a block, you are doing anonymous subclassing. What you are actually doing is `new FXOrder() { /constructor, methods, getters and setters/ }`.